# Date.now() 10 seconds ago

Tags: javascript, jasmine, datejs

I am trying to write a Jasmine test that evaluates some times. Previously I was using `Moment.js`to compute times but I am trying to use Date.now() in some places in order to improve speed. Is there anyway to do something like `moment(time).add(1, "minutes")` with `Date.js`?

Comment: I believe you mean using the JavaScript `Date` class, not *date.js* - that's another library.

Answer (score 5):

[`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) gives you the current time in milliseconds since the epoch.

You can add X minutes by adding X * 60,000 milliseconds to that time.

```js
var now = Date.now();
console.log(new Date(now).getMinutes());
console.log(new Date(now + (1 * 60000)).getMinutes());
console.log(new Date(now + (2 * 60000)).getMinutes());
console.log(new Date(now + (3 * 60000)).getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Datejs library, any of the following options are possible:

```
new Date().addMinutes(1)
new Date().add(1).minute()
new Date().add({ minutes: 1 });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to use this, just LITERALLY COPY ALL of this code & just import it in your component or where ever & just place in your ISOstring() date inside: `showTimeAgo("2022-06-20T13:42:29-05:00")` & you will get automatic time updates for every scenario.

*sidenote*: I made an npm package for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/showtimeago

```
export const showTimeAgo = () => {
    const MONTH_NAMES = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December',
    ];

    function getOrdinalNum() {
        return (
            n +
            (n > 0
                ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][
                      (n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10
                  ]
                : '')
        );
    }

    function getFormattedDate(
        date,
        preformattedDate = false,
        hideYear = false
    ) {
        const day = date.getDate();
        const month = MONTH_NAMES[date.getMonth()];
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        let hours = date.getHours();
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();

        let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

        switch(true){
            case (hours > 12):
                hours = hours - 12;
                break;
            case (hours === 0):
                hours = 12;
                break;
            case(minutes < 10):
                minutes = `0${minutes}`;
                break;
            case(preformattedDate):
            // Today at 10:20am
            // Yesterday at 10:20am
                return `${preformattedDate} at ${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;

            case(hideYear):
                // January 10th at 10:20pm
                return `${month} ${getOrdinalNum(
                    day
                )}, at ${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
            default:
                // January 10th 2022 at 10:20pm
                return `${month} ${getOrdinalNum(
                    day
                )}, ${year} at ${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
        }
        
    }

    // --- Main function
    function timeAgo(dateParam) {
        if (!dateParam) {
            return null;
        }

        const date =
            typeof dateParam === 'object' ? dateParam : new Date(dateParam);
        const DAY_IN_MS = 86400000; // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        const today = new Date();

        const yesterday = new Date(today - DAY_IN_MS);

        const seconds = Math.round((today - date) / 1000);
        const minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
        const hour = Math.round(seconds / 3600);
        const day = Math.round(seconds / 86400);
        const month = Math.round(seconds / 2629800);
        const year = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
        const isToday = today.toDateString() === date.toDateString();
        const isYesterday =
            yesterday.toDateString() === date.toDateString();
        const isThisYear = today.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear();

        switch(true){
            case (seconds < 5):
                return 'now';
            case (seconds < 60):
                return `${seconds} seconds ago`;
            case (seconds < 90):
                return 'about a minute ago';
            case (minutes < 60):
                return `${minutes} minutes ago`;
            case (hour === 1 && hour < 2):
                return `${hour} hour ago`; // 1 hour ago
            case (hour > 1 && hour <= 12):
                return `${hour} hours ago`; // 2 hours ago
            case (isToday):
                return getFormattedDate(date, 'Today'); // Today at 10:20am
            case (isYesterday): 
                return getFormattedDate(date, 'Yesterday'); // Yesterday at 10:20am
            case(day > 1 && day <= 30):
                return `${day} days ago`; // 2 days ago
            case (isThisYear):
                return getFormattedDate(date, false, true); // January 10th at 10:20pm 
            case (day > 30 && month <= 1):
                return `${hour} month ago`; // 1 month ago
            case (month > 1 && month <= 12):
                return `${month} months ago`; // 2 months ago
            case (year === 1):
                return `${year} year ago`; // 1 year ago
            case (year > 1):
                return `${year} years ago`; // 2 years ago
            default:
                return getFormattedDate(date); // January 10th 2022 at 10:20pm
        }
    }

    return timeAgo(date);
};

console.log(showTimeAgo("2022-06-20T13:42:29-05:00"));-05:00"))
```